# Speed of different inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, velocity

[image]

Assume friction-less,  an object was release from the top, what is its speed at the lower end of the slope?

I tried $v= \sqrt {2*9.0m/s^2*5m}$, but I doubt if it's a correct answer, any help?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please review our homework policy in the help center. Questions like this one are against that policy.

Comment: Hi 0xcafebabe and welcome to Physics.SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. See [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [Should any check my work questions be made on topic?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) posts on meta for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy is conserved. So loss of PE = gain of KE. PE lost $=mgh$, KE gained $=mv^2/2$ where $v$ is the speed at the foot of the second ramp, as the body started from rest.

So solve 
$$mv^2/2=mgh$$
for $v$ where $h=15m$ and $g=9.81m/s^2$.